# Display array in input field as an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Here is my plunker,
https://plnkr.co/edit/stKf1C5UnCKSbMp1Tyne?p=preview

```
angular.module('listExample', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = ['morpheus', 'neo', 'trinity'];
}]);
```

```
<body ng-app="listExample">
  <form name="myForm" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <label>List: <input name="namesInput" ng-model="names" required></label>

  <br>
  <tt>names = {{names}}</tt><br/>

 </form>
</body>
```

`$scope.names` is an array and when used to display in input field of html, it is displayed as `morpheus,neo,trinity`
But how to display it as `["morpheus","neo","trinity"]` in html input field

And when added or removed an element from the array in the input field, update $scope.names with the new values

Answer (score 0):

You could use `$scope.$watchCollection` on the array, or `$scope.watch` on the input field, then depending on which way you are updating either use `JSON.stringify` or `JSON.parse`:

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('listExample', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = ['morpheus', 'neo', 'trinity'];
    $scope.value = JSON.stringify($scope.names)
    $scope.$watch("value", function() {
        try {
          $scope.names = JSON.parse($scope.value)  
        } catch (e) {}
    })
    $scope.$watchCollection("names", function() {
       $scope.value = JSON.stringify($scope.names)
    })
    $scope.addName = function() {
      $scope.names.push('mr. anderson');
    }
  }]);
})(window.angular);

/*
Copyright 2019 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.7.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  

  
</head>
<body ng-app="listExample">
  <form name="myForm" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <label>List: <input name="namesInput" ng-model="value" required></label>
  <button ng-click="addName()">Test</button>
  <br>
  <tt>names = {{names}}</tt><br/>
  
 </form>
</body>
</html>

<!-- 
Copyright 2019 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license
-->
```

Answer (score 0):

One can use a custom directive with a formatter and parser for arrays:

```
app.directive('toFromArray', function(){
  return{
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
      ctrl.$parsers.push(toArray);
      ctrl.$formatters.push(fromArray);

      function toArray(viewValue){       
        return viewValue && viewValue.split(',');
      }
      function fromArray(model) {
        console.log(model);
        return model.join();
      }
    }
  };
})
```

### Usage

```
<input name="namesInput" ng-model="names" to-from-array>
```

The [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/BcPhxh7o8XQ4B70PcUQs?p=preview)

For more information, see

- [AngularJS ngModel Controller API Reference - $formatters](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$formatters)
- [AngularJS ngModel Controller API Reference - $parsers](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$parsers)